# Convert Java Swing to web-based Application

Tags: java, swing, web-applications

I have Java swing application. I want to convert to web base application. What is easiest way?
Is there any tool available, preferably open source code?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

AjaxSwing is a run-time tool and needs a server license for commercial use.

You might want to try [Mia Transformer](http://www.mia-software.com) -parts of the website are in French-. They change Swing Java code to GWT Java Code and GWT changes it to Javascript and then if you want you can use Google V8 compiler for faster execution. Of course it is not 100%. We are going to try it for a large project and see if it works.

The other link provided to us was [SwingWeb](http://swingweb.sourceforge.net/swingweb/). Have not checked it out though.

Will keep you posted. If you come across a workable solution please share.

Comment: Where to get that `Mia Transformer`? At the website I cannot understand how to find, download and use it..

Comment: As of 2018, Mia Transformer seems to be as dead as a project can possibly be: it's gone from the Mia Software site, and the only reference I can find to it anywhere on the web is in this StackOverflow answer! SwingWeb is at least still available, but the last stable release was in 2006 and the last beta release in 2007.

Answer (score 21):

There is a new open source project [webswing.org](http://www.webswing.org). It is a web server where you deploy your swing application. The application is rendered to html canvas through websockets, so you get the exact same look and feel like on desktop.

Answer (score 12):

For a Java programmer [the Vaadin framework](https://vaadin.com/swing) is very similar to Java Swing.

Architecturally, Vaadin and Swing applications are of course quite different (web vs desktop), but because the UI logic in Vaadin applications is run on the server side (in a JVM), all the Java classes and application logic from Swing applications is typically fully reusable. You can see in the [hello-world sample](https://github.com/vaadin/hello-world/blob/master/src/main/java/org/vaadin/samples/helloworld/HelloWorldUI.java) how similar the event-diven programming model is to Swing.

Furthermore, Vaadin effectively hides all the web specific details (html, css, rpc,...) from Java application programmers, making it a familiar and effective tool to convert old Swing applications to modern HTML5 web applications.

Answer (score 7):

There is actually a magic tool you could use to convert desktop apps to web apps:  [AjaxSwing](http://www.creamtec.com/products/ajaxswing/)

But note that it can only convert very simple swing apps. If you use complex renderers, you may not get right results. Also its not free.

Answer (score 5):

You can think about **Java Web Start** it's not converting the application but you can use your application as web based...

Comment: For more details, see the [Java Web Start tag info.](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).

Comment: It has been removed from the JDK but lives on as https://openwebstart.com/

Answer (score 1):

This tool: http://sourceforge.net/projects/j-wings/ is a API compatible replacement for Swing but runs in an servlet engine renders to HTML.

Comment: Not looking very promising as of 2018: last update 2014-02-21, and advertises "developing web based AJAX applications in a way like developing Swing based applications" rather than an actual drop-in replacement.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is late but [Webswing](https://www.webswing.org/) lets you run Java Swing applictions in your webbrowser.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! As the usage of links is useful, please also consider on explaining or providing some context, for instance using examples, on why the mentioned answer helps the OP.

Comment: Another vote for webswing, quick and easy way to run Swing apps on the web.

Answer (score 1):

For the current visitors, Jetbrains has a new open source projector called Projector which can be used to render swing applications in web and they are using this to render their Intellij IDE also.

Below is the excerpt from their github

> Projector is a way to run Swing applications without any windowing system and accessing them either locally or remotely.

[JetBrains Projector](https://github.com/JetBrains/projector-server/blob/master/docs/Projector.md)

This project is still in incubator stage. But I have tried using it with their IDE and its working great.

Answer (score -1):

As Vinod mentioned Java Web Start is the easiest way.  Another alternative is to convert the application to an Applet that you can run from a web page.

Comment: Applets are decomissioned from many browsers. It is not a good solution.

Comment: Webstart has also been removed from the JDK but is still available as https://openwebstart.com/