# what is the role of apache server in java swing application (3 tier)?

Tags: java, apache, swing, 3-tier, easyphp

I have made a Java Swing application, in the GUI the user can select the type of element and choose a date then the element's informations will be shown on a JTable.i used easyPHP to create the DB.

so what is the role of apache server in this case!

can i consider it like an application server ?

Comment: The application server is a centralized container for the business logic. It acts as a gateway between the client and the database (and other data sources) and executes the required business logic for the application. *"can i consider it like an application server ?"* - Consider what?

Comment: in web application the apache server gets http query from the client and send an sql query to the DB server right !! i am confused if he did the same thing with swing java application ?

Comment: I wouldn't consider a application accessing a database directly a "application server", there's no access control and each client could be a different version, meaning there business logic could be different, the application server is meant to protect against this

Comment: so it is impossible to create a 3 tier architecture application using java swing ?

Comment: No, the Swing app would need to to connect to some other service which performed the underlying business logic, may using HTTP/JSON, HTTP/XML, SOAP or even RMI

Comment: okay thanks for the explanation. but i still can talk about MVC !

Comment: MVC is a over broad concept which can be applied to multiple layers of just about any application :P

Answer (score 3):

A Java swing application (AFAIK out of the box, for alternatives see below) is not available over HTTP/S (and is therefore not classified as a web application) and Apache is a web server (with features such as proxy, TLS terminator etc.). Therefore there would be no need for a web server such as Apache to front your Swing application.

Apache web server is not an application server for a Swing application per se. Although it can run applications in different programming languages such as php through loading of modules. It however does not run Java web applications.

An application server in a Java perspective would be Tomcat, Glassfish, JBoss, WebLogic etc. An application server hosts an application and could provide a set of services such as Naming, HTTP processing and so on.

Perhaps you are referring to Apache Tomcat instead of Apache Web Server. If so, you would be right on the mark as that is an application server for Java web applications.

If you would like to make your application available through HTTP and enjoy the myriad and expansive benefits of an application server, I would recommend you to rethink on using Swing and utilize a technology built over Java Servlets such as JSPs, Spring MVC and so on.

If you would still like to make the Swing application available through a web server (through HTTP/S) there are some solutions out there but I have not tried any of those. Please do a search on "Swing available on HTTP" in that case. I have also provided a link as well.

You can read up on Application Servers on this wiki [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_server#Java_application_servers).

You can read up on an HTTP end point for a Swing application [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5470867/convert-java-swing-to-web-based-application).

Comment: it is not a java web application !!

Comment: @HaiderRzig: yes, please read the very first line which implies that.

Comment: If this answers your query, please accept the answer.

Answer (score 2):

This Apache is not used in your application. You installed easyPHP so Apache comes with that to provide PHP programming environment.

Moreover Apache is a web server. So any web based application can be deploy here. PHP is a web programming language sot it requires Apache or any other web server.

But your application is standalone developed with JAVA SWING. So you can stop Apache server and check everything is running fine or not.