# Is there a way to implement a Java application (game) into a website using JavaScript (Vue.js)

Tags: javascript, java, vue.js

**Background:** I am building my own website built with JavaScript (`vue.js`) and I would like to add a `Java` game that I have developed. The java game currently uses `JFrame` for GUI and already has basic keyboard controls (keys: up, down, right, left, v, enter, esc). I would like it to appear in an embedded frame on the page. I'm still fairly new with `JavaScript` and intermediate with `Java`, but I'm trying to learn as much as possible.

**Tools:** `Eclipse` for Java, `Virtual Studio Code` for vue.js

**My take on it:** After digging around, my thought on the answer has something to do with REST APIs. I looked at many documents on REST APIs but all strayed off my goal. It would be awesome to confirm or point me in the right direction for answering this question.
These are the sites I visited that I thought were a bit useful:

https://forum.vuejs.org/t/java-vuejs/41248

https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

**Questions I have:**

a) What is the best way to implement this on the webpage?

b) Will these controls continue to work if I were to implement the game (if possible, based on answer a)?

c) Will JFrame be an issue on the webpage (as well, if possible, based on answer a)?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: The days of Java as part of web applications are basically long gone, I'm afraid. Certainly *new* web applications.

Comment: Hmm, that sucks.  I just need to be able to show my work. What do you recommend would be the language to use? C++?

Comment: You can’t use Java like that anymore... If you want to embed a game into your site your best bet would probably be to remake it using JavaScript and a rendering library like three.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to use Swing (I assume it by your mentioning of JFrame), the answer to your question is probably here: [Convert Java Swing to web-based Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5470867/convert-java-swing-to-web-based-application). There are some theoretical options, but I believe this approach might be highly troublesome.

I would recommend taking another approach: using a Java game library that allows you to export your game to HTML5. Then you will be able to embed it easily on the website. One such example could be libGDX: https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/

Another advantage is that writing a game using a library dedicated for games will be much easier in the long run than in Swing, which is more suited for static applications.